# Homework hint: use dot product to show inscribed angle of a semicircle is a right angle

Tags: vectors

I'm currently stuck on a homework problem from MIT OCW 18.02 multivariate calculus.

The problem is in a section on dot products, and asks to use vector methods (without components) to show that the inscribed angle of a semicircle is a right angle.

I have been toying around with it the past couple of days. The first thing I did was sketch it out, and I quickly came to a solution by summing up the angles in my sketch. (I drew two triangles and determined the relationship between the angles, which led me to deduce the inscribed angle was $\frac{\pi}{2}$)

But that solution doesn't feel in keeping with the rest of the problems, which makes me wonder what I missed.

I know I could just peek the answer, but I also know that wouldn't *really* help. I would prefer a gentle nudge in the right direction instead. Can you provide a hint that may point me in the direction I need to think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :**

Since vectors encode same information as Geometry, we make use of same triangles in (your) Euclidean geometry proof.

Fix the center of semicircle as the origin. Let $A,B$ be the position vectors of end points of the base diameter and let $P$ be the position vector of any point on the semicircle. We have to prove
$$(P-A)\cdot (P-B)=0$$

Suppose $A=\vec{a}$, what would be $B$? Let $P=\vec{r}$.
Now that we know two sides of each triangle, we can find out the third.

Also note that $|OP|=|OA|=|OB|$. Now we can find out $PA \cdot PB$ and see if it evaluates to zero.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I think this is begging the question. Doesnt pythagoras assume a right triangle, which is what I am trying to prove. But I think I might keep puzzling on alone before seeking more hints 

Comment: @AndrewMicallef You're right. The previous hint was incorrect. Please see the edit.

Comment: This feels profitable, though my last comment turned out to be due to a silly mistake on my worksheet, I still feel Im headed in the right direction, now I am using the dot product as the basis for the geometric solution

Comment: solved it!
So I had to peek the solution, and was surprised because the official solution used a distributive property that I didn't know about. And so even after looking it up i was puzzled, had to go back and work through so more examples. Turns out you need to consider the diagonals (ie $\vec{(P-A)} + \vec{(P-B)}$ and $\vec{(P-A)} - \vec{(P-B)}$). You can show these have the same length, and from there use distributive property to rewrite the magnitudes in terms of $\vec{(P-A)} \cdot \vec{(P-B)}$...

Answer (score 1):

One can compute the dot product with a rotated coordinate system:

[image]

With the tangent and diameter to the circle at the inscribed angle as axes, we get
$$
\begin{align}
(B-C)\cdot(A-C)
&=\overbrace{\overbrace{\ (r+x)\ }^{B-C}\overbrace{\ (r-x)\ }^{A-C}}^\text{diametric}+\overbrace{\overbrace{\quad y\quad\phantom{()}}^{B-C}\overbrace{\quad(-y)\quad}^{A-C}}^\text{tangential}\\[6pt]
%&=r^2-x^2-y^2
\end{align}
$$
However, I am not sure if this avoids the "without components" restriction.

---

Evidently, the answer above is not what they wanted for "without components".  Here is a diagram of the answer given

[image]

Comment: I'd actually moved on from this a few weeks ago, but I really want to say thankyou for introducing me to the `\overbrace` command, that actually is coming in helpful right now for keeping track of all the substitutions I am doing in these nasty integrals.